# Why is System.Speech.Recognition not detecting or inserting into textbox?

Tags: c#, .net

On visual studio code; I'm trying to get a text box to be used as a speech to text. However, when I enable it no error get thrown, nor does any speech appear. So, not entirely sure were I went wrong here. Very new to C# and visual studio. Any help is appreciated!! :) My mic is set to the default device and is able to detect me speaking. Other function such as copy to clipboard and clear work.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Speech;
  using System.Speech.Recognition;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace MercyProto
    {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Grammar grammar;
    public Thread RecThread;
    public Boolean RecognizerState = true;
    public SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        GrammarBuilder build = new GrammarBuilder();
        build.AppendDictation();

        grammar = new Grammar(build);

        

        recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(grammar);
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs> 
      (recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        

        RecognizerState = true;
        RecThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RecThreadFunction));
        RecThread.Start();



    }
    public void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Recognizer recognizes the speech

        if (!RecognizerState)
            return;

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            textBox1.Text += (" " + e.Result.Text.ToLower());
            //This will add a space between each word you say
        });
      }
       public void RecThreadFunction()
       {
        

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                recognizer.Recognize();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Handles errors
                //Won't hear you, nothing will happen
            }
        }
  private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        RecognizerState = true;
      }

    private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecognizerState = false;
    }

    private void button23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: "no error get thrown" -- `try
            {
                recognizer.Recognize();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Handles errors
                //Won't hear you, nothing will happen
            }` -- are you sure?

Comment: Yes, when I press button21_Click it should turn on speech to text in textbox1 however, no speech to text appears in textbox1 and no error gets thrown.